# При переходе между сценами в Unity не срабатывает анимация

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, unity3d-ui

Создал в Canvas картинку, сделал ей анимацию высветления и затем затухания (альфа канал картинки).
Делаю старт сцены, всё работает отлично. Но, если в эту сцену перейти из другой сцены, то анимация не будет работать. В Animator показывает что включил анимацию, но не проигрывает (в начале словно завис). Пробовал через скрипт, мол если старт сцены, то срабатывает триггер на активацию анимации, но и тут не работает. Не могу понять в чём дело.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При переходе от сцены к сцене вы используете где-нибудь в коде **Time.timeScale = 0.0f**  ?

Comment: Блин, как ты точно подметил. И вправду стоял 0. Спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в `Time.timeScale`, который был равен нулю. У меня была пауза в конце предыдущей сцены, и получается, при переходе в новую время стояло на месте.

Накинул скрипт, чтобы при старте сцены `Time.timeScale = 1f`, и всё заработало.

Благодарю за ответ: [Александр Даниловский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/295192/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80-%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9).